# Java Inheritence or static method

Tags: java, inheritance, static

There is an abstract class called `AbstractAgent` and currently there are 27 classes who are extending this class.

I have started developing some agents and all my 5 agents are extending `AbstractAgent` class.

Now I observed that there is a `getFilePath()` which I am copy-pasting in all my 5 agents. Then I realized that out of existing 27 classes also there were many classes who had this method. I thought it would be a good idea to put this method in the base class `AbstractAgent` and let everybody use this method. But I dont want all existing classes to change their code I have changed the method name so that going forward anyone can use it.

The person who did my code review suggested me not to touch `AbstractAgent` class because it is already being used by existing clients and put this method is some utility class.

I am not convinced by his argument. Anybody want to pitch in their thoughts.

Comment: imho, that's a poor argument, I support refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `getFilePath()` method is exactly the same for all of `AbstractAgent`'s subclasses, then by all means go ahead and pull it up to the abstract class (use your IDE's refactoring tools), delete it from the subclasses then run unit tests (you *do* have unit tests, right?) and check that everything is working fine.

If there are differences between *some* implementations of `getFilePath()`, but most of them are identical, it's still a good idea to pull the most common implementation up to the abstract class, delete it from the subclasses that use it and override the method in the subclasses in those cases where the implementation differs.

Now, if there's just too much variability between the different implementations of the method, leave the code base untouched.

Defining a static method in a utility class (say, `FileUtil`) makes sense only if the method is not directly related to the functionality of the Agent classes, or if the method could be of use in some other part of the object hierarchy, not directly related to agents.

Comment: getFilePath() method functionality is same in all the classes

Answer (score 5):

In this case because the `AbstractAgent` class is already being used by other classes, and as you mentioned yourself **NOT** all the classes implement this method then you should indeed NOT change the `AbstractAgent`. You can however extend `AbstractAgent` in another abstract subclass called say `AbstractAgentWithFilePath`, which declares that additional method you want, and then have those classes extend the `AbstractAgentWithFilePath` class instead.

Comment: This is a good solution but creating one more class hierarchy just for one method does not make sense to me. AbstractAgent is something standard and everybody would be extending this class. Asking them to use AbstractAgentWithFilePath is little difficult. But logically you are right.

Comment: I like this, except I think he may be criticized for introducing a new class in the hierarchy entirely based around what is probably an insignificant utility method.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Adding common logic to the parent class is one of the strong sides of abstract classes and such addition is a forward compatible change. Unless, of course, you don't know about some uses of this class and your newly added method has the same name. But even then, if subclass overwrite such method, its own method will be invoked, so it is still a forward compatible change.

Comment: Makes sense. This is inline with my thoughts.

Comment: Not true in general. Overload resolution can easily be a problem and break compatibility.. "Sorry we added a function and now your code is calling the wrong function" is a great way to make friends with clients of your library..

Comment: +1 to this line of thought. Adding an overloaded method should not break backwards compatibility. Worst case scenario you give it a different name and then it ***definitely*** does not break backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Perception It certainly can break backwards compatibility and there's no way you can guarantee that a function name isn't in use by some arbitrary external subclass..

Comment: @Voo - hmmmm, please elaborate how adding a new method can break backwards compatibility with existing code, based on the user case the OP described.

Comment: @Perception As soon as the function takes a parameter, overload resolution kicks in. Suddenly calling a completely different function you're not even aware exists, is certainly problematic. Now I don't think there's a problem with a function that takes no parameters, but I haven't spent much time mulling that over and it certainly isn't universally useful.

Comment: @Voo - not sure I follow, overloading is a core feature of the language. Even if the overloaded method takes parameters by default the most specific method will be matched. You only run into problems with generic types or if you are performing broadening casts that hide the actual parameter type to perform the 'overload resolution' against.

Comment: @Perception [Simple example](http://pastebin.com/vL6WDmvu). Run with/without function in `A` and see the different output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8650/discussion-between-perception-and-voo)

Answer (score 0):

if the method is tightly related to the Agent classes, put it inside the abstract is a good option, but if it is not, put it in another utility class which handles all File related actions would be acceptable,.

Answer (score 0):

There's no right answer here.  Only you, your coworkers, and your company know how and where AbstractAgent is used, and how changing it impacts various different teams, departments, or customers.  Decisions about where to locate code are often more political and social than driven by "clean room" design choices.

From a purely code perspective, I support radical refactoring: get rid of ALL the duplicate code in ALL subclasses of AbstractAgent, and move everyone to the new getFilePath() in AbstractAgent.

But you may not have the authority to do this, and you may get pushback.  Or maybe getFilePath() varies slightly sometimes (you were not clear about this.) In that case, whatever choice you make seems like a compromise.  Your code reviewer may be pushing back against 'getFilePath2()' in AbstractAgent because it sheds light on the problem of imperfect code reuse and feels like it is "polluting" the superclass with a temporary workaround to what should really be solved by bringing everyone up to date with truly common shared code in the superclass.  Who knows.

Perhaps a static utility method is a better choice until such time as a complete refactoring can be done.